# complex multiple associations save in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am saving an Employee which is associated with a hasMany relationship with Courses through EmployeesCourses table. This all works fine, the employee gets added and the new employee_id and the course_id get created into EmployeesCourses table.

I am now trying to add a record into the users table for the employee and the new user_id gets saved with the employee as it gets created. All other recored still get saved but I do not get anytime for the users table and no id in Employee.user_id

EmployeesController.php

```
public function add()
{
    $employee = $this->Employees->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $employee = $this->Employees->patchEntity($employee, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => ['Users', 'Courses']
        ]);
        if ($this->Employees->save($employee)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The employee has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $businesses = $this->Employees->Businesses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $courses = $this->Employees->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('employee', 'users', 'businesses', 'courses'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['employee']);
}
```

employees add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($employee) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Employee') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user.email');
        echo $this->Form->input('user.new_password', ['value' => '', 'type' => 'password']);
        echo $this->Form->input('user.confirm_password', ['value' => '', 'type' => 'password']);
        echo $this->Form->input('business_id', ['options' => $hotels]);
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('surname');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_num');
        echo $this->Form->input('courses._ids', ['options' => $courses]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Employees Model

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('employees');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',

    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Businesses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'hotel_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'course_id',
        'joinTable' => 'courses_employees'
    ]);
}
```

Users model

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('email');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasOne('Employees', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasOne('Businesses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: do you have separate tables for Employee and User models ? if yes, since  Employee is special kind of User you can simply create another association to User model aliased as Employee. it's explained http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: I have read over the doc again and sorry I am not fully sure what you mean. I have a basic understanding what you mean by User model aliased as Employee but I don't see a mention in the doc how it might work inside Cakephp.

Comment: sorry that link is for 3.0 docs. search for 2.* associations instead.